# magento website url is make a short

Tags: url, .htaccess

I wanted to make a short URL possible ? 
my hosting server :bluehost
domain :different company to godomall

```
ex) http://www.example.com/magento/index.php ->
 http://www.example.com/ or http://example.com
```

Comment: You want to remove index.php right

Comment: delete index.php ? ?@Kothari

Comment: Goto system -> configuration -> web -> Use Web Server Rewrites set yes

Comment: @MagenX  example.com/magento/index.php < -index.php delete complete . but shwoing /magento/ what problem?

Comment: Did place all file into magento folder

Answer (score 1):

Login in admin panel and then go to:
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization and for Use Web Server Rewrites change dropdown menu to "YES". Click Save Config button on the right top corner.

Comment: example.com/magento/index.php  < -index.php delete complete . but shwoing /magento/ what problem?